# How to copy all .xls files from INBOUND folder in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, export-to-csv, import-from-excel, ssconvert

I want to copy all `.xls` files only from the INBOUND folder to the target folder and convert all `.xls` files to `.csv` files.

Below is the code I wrote but it is not working properly.

```
#!/bin/bash
SRC_PATH=/bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/*/INBOUND/*
TGT_PATH=/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/New_Vendors/Xls_Convert/

cp $SRC_PATH {*.xls} $TGT_PATH

cd $TGT_PATH

for i in
do 
ssconvert i i.csv
done
```

Comment: What is not working in your attempt?

Comment: @Inian- getting coppied with all the file ie .pdf,.xlsx,.jpg and converion not happening.

Comment: Try pasting your code into ShellCheck... http://www.shellcheck.net/#

Answer (score 0):

To copy all xls files:

```
cp /path_to_INBOUND/*.xls /path_to_target/.
```

To do some action with those files:

```
cd /path_to_target/
for i in *; do ssconvert i i.csv; done
```

(Supposing that ssconvert command works in that way, I don't know it)

Comment: @linuxfan Sure! It is also possible (even easier) I edit my answer.